# How to understand higher dimenstion structures(i.e hypercube)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, machine-learning

I am reading a book on ML there is a chapter on `Dimensionality Reduction` I found a very subtle paragraph related to hypercube paragraph is given blow

> It turns out that many things behave very differently in high-dimensional space. For
>   example, if you pick a random point in a unit square (a 1 × 1 square), it will have only
>   about a 0.4% chance of being located less than 0.001 from a border (in other words, it
>   is very unlikely that a random point will be “extreme” along any dimension). But in a
>   10,000-dimensional unit hypercube (a 1 × 1 × ⋯ × 1 cube, with ten thousand 1s), this
>   probability is greater than 99.999999%. Most points in a high-dimensional hypercube
>   are very close to the border.3
>   square, the distance between these two points will be, on average, roughly 0.52. If you
>   pick two random points in a unit 3D cube, the average distance will be roughly 0.66.
>   But what about two points picked randomly in a 1,000,000-dimensional hypercube?
>   Well, the average distance, believe it or not, will be about 408.25 (roughly
>   1, 000, 000/6)! This is quite counter intuitive: how can two points be so far apart
>   when they both lie within the same unit hypercube? This fact implies that high dimensional
>   datasets are at risk of being very sparse:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some tricks I use to "get a feel" for higher dimension:

-understanding how to create a teseract (4d cube) from eight 3d cubes

-imagining a 4d object with advancing time - with the time you go along an axis and the 5d or n-d objects with arrays of such (in the first go-through, you go throug x5=0, in the second x5 = 1 and so on)

-computing how things like rotating work in higher dimension(In 4d you can rotate around a plane!)

-and especially in your case: look how the euclidian distance changes in higher dimension

Answer (score 0):

Space seems to expand in higher dimensions simply because there are more degrees of freedom of movement. Although this is mincing words a little bit, while spacial dimensions can go as high as we wish, the typical way that we compute distance remains a one dimensional thing - the one dimensional distance between two points in 100 dimensions is far less significant than the one dimensional distance between two points in three dimsensions. I suggest you have a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwAD6dRSVyI

Answer (score 0):

The first phenomenon comes from the probability that all coordinates are non-extremal falling exponentially with the dimension $n$. The second comes from the longest diagonal being $\sqrt{n}$.